# Can I change a when with check for null to a different approach?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

In Kotlin is there a more "Kotlin" way to do the following?

```
fun parse(inputSample: Sample): List<String> = 
   when {
     inputSample.foo != null -> parse(inputSample.foo)
     inputSample.bar != null -> parse(inputSample.bar)
     else -> emptyList()
  }
```

I suspect that check for `null` with `when` can be written differently in Kotlin

Answer (score 7):

You can use scoping function to reduce "redundant" code:

```
fun parse(inputSample: Sample): List<String> = inputSample.run {
    when {
        foo != null -> parse(foo)
        bar != null -> parse(bar)
        else -> emptyList()
    }
}
```

Or combining with elvis operator (note this assumes `foo` and `bar` are of same type):

```
fun parse(inputSample : Sample) : List<String> = inputSample.run {
    (foo ?: bar)?.let { parse(it) } ?: emptyList()
}
```

Comment: Instead of scope function, you could also make `parse()` an extension function

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is a more Kotlin way, but you can also do the following

```
fun parse(inputSample: Sample): List<String> = 
      inputSample.foo?.let { parse(it) } ?: inputSample.bar?.let {parse(it) } ?: emptyList()
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me this alternative. It seems less readable than `when` but thanks for showing that to me to know

Comment: I improved it a bit to use "it"